# Pandas: How to extract columns on new columns which contain special separators?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

My data frame has some columns which contains digits and words. Before the digits and words sometimes there are special character like ">*".
The column are mostly divided in , or /. Based on separators, I want to section it into new columns and delete it.

Reproduced my dataframe and with my code:

```py
d = {'error': [ 
'test,121',
'123',   
'test,test',
'>errrI1GB,213',
'*errrI1GB,213',
'*errrI1GB/213',
'*>errrI1GB/213',
'>*errrI1GB,213',
'>test,   test',
'>>test,   test',
'>>:test,test',
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['error'] = df['error'].str.replace(' ', '')
df[['error1', 'error2']] = df['error'].str.extract('.*?(\w*)[,|/](\w*)')
df
```

So far my approach is first to remove the whitespaces with

`df['error'] = df['error'].str.replace(' ', '')`

Than I constructed my regex  with this help 
 https://regex101.com/r/UHzTOq/13

`.*?(\w*)[,|/](\w*)`

Afterwards I delete the messy column with:

`df.drop(columns =["error"], inplace = True)`

My single values in the row are not considered. Therefore I get a NaN as a result. How to include them in my regex?

Solution is:

```py
df[['error1', 'error2']] = df['error'].str.extract(r'^[>*:]*(.*?)(?:[,|\\](.*))?$')
```

Comment: So what help you want? You seems to be getting what you want...

Comment: @Abbas sorry updated my problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we'd like to add those values with only a `test` or a `123` in `error1` column, maybe then we'd just slightly modify your original expression:

```
^.*?(\w*)\s*(?:[,|/]\s*(\w*))?\s*$
```

I'm pretty sure there should be other easier ways though.

#### Test

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'error': [ 
'test,121',
'123',   
'test',   
'test,test',
'>errrI1GB,213',
'*errrI1GB,213',
'*errrI1GB/213',
'*>errrI1GB/213',
'>*errrI1GB,213',
'>test,   test',
'>>test,   test',
'>>:test,test',
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['error1'] = df['error'].str.replace(r'(?mi)^.*?(\w*)\s*(?:[,|/]\s*(\w*))?\s*$', r'\1')
df['error2'] = df['error'].str.replace(r'(?mi)^.*?(\w*)\s*(?:[,|/]\s*(\w*))?\s*$', r'\2')

print(df)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7xXIrc/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7xXIrc/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Output

```
             error    error1 error2
0         test,121      test    121
1              123       123       
2             test      test       
3        test,test      test   test
4    >errrI1GB,213  errrI1GB    213
5    *errrI1GB,213  errrI1GB    213
6    *errrI1GB/213  errrI1GB    213
7   *>errrI1GB/213  errrI1GB    213
8   >*errrI1GB,213  errrI1GB    213
9    >test,   test      test   test
10  >>test,   test      test   test
11    >>:test,test      test   test
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]